# how to setup efk logging in aks cluster nodes?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, azure-aks, fluentd

how to set up efk logging in aks cluster nodes?

Below are my spec files for efk logging in aks clusters.

```
# Elasticsearch.yaml

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: es-cluster
  namespace: logging
spec:
  serviceName: logs-elasticsearch
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.5.0
        resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1000m
            requests:
              cpu: 500m
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: rest
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: inter-node
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data-logging
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        env:
          - name: cluster.name
            value: k8s-logs
          - name: node.name
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: discovery.seed_hosts
            value: "es-cluster-0.logs-elasticsearch,es-cluster-1.logs-elasticsearch,es-cluster-2.logs-elasticsearch"
          - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
            value: "es-cluster-0,es-cluster-1,es-cluster-2"
          - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
            value: "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      initContainers:
      - name: fix-permissions
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data-logging
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - name: increase-vm-max-map
        image: busybox
        command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
      - name: increase-fd-ulimit
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "ulimit -n 65536"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data-logging
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "managed-premium-retain-sc"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 100Gi

---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: logs-elasticsearch
  namespace: logging
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
spec:
  selector:
    app: elasticsearch
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - port: 9200
      name: rest
    - port: 9300
      name: inter-node

########################
# Kibana yaml

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kibana
  labels:
    app: kibana
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kibana
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kibana
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kibana
        image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.5.0
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1000m
          requests:
            cpu: 500m
        env:
          - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS
            value: http://logs-elasticsearch.logging.svc.cluster.local:9200
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5601

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: logs-kibana
spec:
  selector: 
    app: kibana
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 5601
      targetPort: 5601

##################
# fluentd daemonset and rbac,sa,clusterrole specs

apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  labels:
    app: fluentd
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  labels:
    app: fluentd
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  - namespaces
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: fluentd
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: fluentd
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: fluentd
  namespace: default

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  labels:
    app: fluentd
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: fluentd
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: fluentd
    spec:
      serviceAccount: fluentd
      serviceAccountName: fluentd
      containers:
      - name: fluentd
        image: fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1.4.2-debian-elasticsearch-1.1
        env:
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
            value: "logs-elasticsearch.logging.svc.cluster.local"
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
            value: "9200"
          - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME
            value: "http"
          - name: FLUENTD_SYSTEMD_CONF
            value: disable
          - name: FLUENT_UID
            value: "0"
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 512Mi
            cpu: 500m
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log/
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers

          readOnly: true
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log/
      - name: varlibdockercontainers
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/docker/containers
```

The setup is working fine only thing no logs are coming to elasticsearch cluster from fluentd whereas the same spec files work fine inside minikube cluster.

As for this setup kibana is up and able to connect with elasticsearch and the same is the case with fluentd, just logs are not coming inside elasticseach.

What extra configuration needs to be configured to make these config files work with azure k8 service(AKS) cluster nodes?

Answer (score 1):

Had to add below environment variables for Fluentd.

Reference Link: https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset/issues/434

```
          - name: FLUENT_CONTAINER_TAIL_EXCLUDE_PATH
            value: /var/log/containers/fluent*
          - name: FLUENT_CONTAINER_TAIL_PARSER_TYPE
            value: /^(?<time>.+) (?<stream>stdout|stderr)( (?<logtag>.))? (?<log>.*)$/
```

Here's the complete spec.

```
# Elasticsearch.yaml

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: es-cluster
  namespace: logging
spec:
  serviceName: logs-elasticsearch
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.5.0
        resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1000m
            requests:
              cpu: 500m
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: rest
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: inter-node
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data-logging
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        env:
          - name: cluster.name
            value: k8s-logs
          - name: node.name
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: discovery.seed_hosts
            value: "es-cluster-0.logs-elasticsearch,es-cluster-1.logs-elasticsearch,es-cluster-2.logs-elasticsearch"
          - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
            value: "es-cluster-0,es-cluster-1,es-cluster-2"
          - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
            value: "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      initContainers:
      - name: fix-permissions
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data-logging
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - name: increase-vm-max-map
        image: busybox
        command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
      - name: increase-fd-ulimit
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "ulimit -n 65536"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data-logging
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "managed-premium-retain-sc"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 100Gi

---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: logs-elasticsearch
  namespace: logging
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
spec:
  selector:
    app: elasticsearch
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - port: 9200
      name: rest
    - port: 9300
      name: inter-node

########################
# Kibana yaml

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kibana
  labels:
    app: kibana
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kibana
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kibana
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kibana
        image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.5.0
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1000m
          requests:
            cpu: 500m
        env:
          - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS
            value: http://logs-elasticsearch.logging.svc.cluster.local:9200
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5601

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: logs-kibana
spec:
  selector: 
    app: kibana
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 5601
      targetPort: 5601

##################
# fluentd daemonset and rbac,sa,clusterrole specs

apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  labels:
    app: fluentd
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  labels:
    app: fluentd
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  - namespaces
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: fluentd
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: fluentd
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: fluentd
  namespace: default

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  labels:
    app: fluentd
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: fluentd
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: fluentd
    spec:
      serviceAccount: fluentd
      serviceAccountName: fluentd
      containers:
      - name: fluentd
        image: fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1.4.2-debian-elasticsearch-1.1
        env:
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
            value: "logs-elasticsearch.logging.svc.cluster.local"
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
            value: "9200"
          - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME
            value: "http"
          - name: FLUENTD_SYSTEMD_CONF
            value: disable
          - name: FLUENT_UID
            value: "0"
          - name: FLUENT_CONTAINER_TAIL_EXCLUDE_PATH
            value: /var/log/containers/fluent*
          - name: FLUENT_CONTAINER_TAIL_PARSER_TYPE
            value: /^(?<time>.+) (?<stream>stdout|stderr)( (?<logtag>.))? (?<log>.*)$/

        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 512Mi
            cpu: 500m
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log/
#        - name: varlibdockercontainers
#          mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
        - name: dockercontainerlogsdirectory
          mountPath: /var/log/pods
          readOnly: true
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log/
 #     - name: varlibdockercontainers
 #       hostPath:
#          path: /var/lib/docker/containers
      - name: dockercontainerlogsdirectory
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log/pods
```